# Add Information To CException And CEmailLogRoute

Tags: php, yii

I've got a number of errors in my CEmailLogRoute. That's fine but I'd like to have more specified information.

For example with 403 access denied errors I'd like to know which Yii::app()->user->id initiated this. 
Possibly I want also to add the roles which the user has.

Is it possible to add information to either CEmailLogRoute or more specific to a CException or to CHttpException.403?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`CLogFilter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogFilter) (or extends it), e.g. in your config :

```
array(
    'class'=>'CEmailLogRoute',
    'levels'=>'error, warning',
    'emails'=>'admin@example.com',
    'filter' => array(
        'class' => 'CLogFilter',
        'prefixUser' => true,
    ),
),
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#logging-context-information